python import issue with similar directory structure
I have the below directory structure:
project_root_dir
├── a
│   └── b
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── test_cases.py
└── subdir
    └── a
        └── b
            └── __init__.py

My PYTHONPATH env is set as below:
export PYTHONPATH=<workspace_path>/project_root_dir/:<workspace_path>/project_root_dir/subdir

I am launching the interpreter from project_root_dir/subdir
# from inside project_root_dir/subdir

import a.b.test_cases

It throwing module not found error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'a.b.test_cases'

The python interpreter will look for that module first under subdir.a.b which it will not find and then look for the module in project_root_dir.a.b where it should be found. (Since both the paths are present in PYTHONPATH). Then why is the error being thrown?
Is there a way I can get it to work?

this must be a problem of conflicting names or shadowing.
Try a different name, project_root_dir/a/b and project_root_dir/subdir/c/d
>>> import a.b
>>> import a.b.test_cases
>>> 
>>> import subdir
>>> import subdir.c
>>> import subdir.c.d


I would recommend to explicitly control the module search path at runtime by modifying sys.path like following
import sys
import os

# Add project root directory to the system path
project_root = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', '..'))
if project_root not in sys.path:
    sys.path.insert(0, project_root)

import a.b.test_cases


For a folder to be a module, it needs a __init__.py file (even if its empty).
Try creating that file inside the a folder.
